# Offsetting UIView isn't moving all view elements

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard

I have a view controller that looks like this: [Normal View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTDox.png)

When the keyboard appears, I want the screen to move upwards so that the textfields don't get covered by the keyboard. I'm using 
`self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, -keyboardHeight)` to move the UIView.

However, when the keyboard appears, it only moves the bottom button: [View Controller with Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YK8x.png)

Why do the rest of the elements in the view controller stay in the same place and how can get them all to move upwards?

Comment: are you using auto layout? You probably did set the textfields at a fixed distance from the top rather than a fixed distance from the bottom or even centered.

Comment: yeah I'm using constraints to the top and center, but why does that matter? The same code used to work when I was using xcode 6 but stopped when I updated it to version 7

Answer (score 0):

You are using auto layout. So you would actually have to add @IBOutlets for each of the constraints set on the other objects. and along with moving the view you would also have to move the constraints the same amount.

Comment: is there any way to select all of the constraints programmatically without creating an @IBOutlet for each one? I have to do this for other views as well that have a lot of contraints

Comment: @wafflecohn yes you have to do this for each, unless you know how to use the stack view